# SharePoint 2016 ADFS change the Trusted Identity provider name

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, adfs, trusted-identity-provider

I have configure ADFS for SharePoint 2016, it is working fine. But now i want to change the ADFS Trusted identity provider name 
I follow this:

```
$spt =Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer
$spt.name ="newname"
$spt.update()
```

Now it change the name but break many things.

- User getting access denied, to fix this looks like I have to migrate
  the users. I have to reconfigure the Object cache as well.
- Custom claims provider not working properly. I am not sure how to fix
  it.

My question is, what is the best way to change the name of the TrustedIdenity?

Answer (score 1):

You're going about the best way to do it. You'll have to update *all* references to the TIP. That includes usernames and any group names or other objects referenced with the previous TIP.

For the custom provider, there may be hard coded or configurable references to the specific TIP name. That is going to be more difficult to identify without source code available to us.